# Alternatives to Raspberry PI

Tags: raspbmc

I know this question may have been asked before. I just want to know if there are any alternatives to the Raspberry Pi. I want to use it as an XMBC station, but the reviews tell me that it's a bit buggy as of now. The video forwarding and the loading times are not very good.

What I get from all this is that a Raspberry Pi is a good machine for beginners to learn programming, but power users might want to look somewhere else.

Finally, here is my question: What are some other alternatives to the Raspberry Pi. They must be compatible with any flavor of linux. One I like is PandaBoard.

Any other suggestion like that would be great. Price range is between $0-240

Comment: After careful consideration I have decided to go with PandaBoard ES from DigiKey website..

Comment: Well actually I am having a hard time deciding between ODROID-X and PandaBoard ES .. They both seem to do the job perfectly fine.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There are a lot of Embedded Linux boards/systems available, here is an overview.

(This list is by no means complete, anyone that is missing something please add it to the list to make it as complete as possible.)

### x86 based

---

1. **VIA ARTiGO A1200**

   **CPU:** 1.0GHz VIA Eden™ X2 processor, 
   **GPU:** VIA Chrome 9
   **RAM Memory:** Up to 4GB of DDR3 1066 SODIMM RAM, 
   **NAND Flash:** None,
   **Storage:** Built-in 2.5” SATA, Built-in CFast socket, 
   **I/O:** HDMI, VGA, 4 USB 2.0, 2 GigaLAN, 2 COM, 1 CFast socket,
   **Other Features:** HD, MPEG-2, WMV9, VC1 & H.264 video decoding hardware acceleration,
   **Site:** http://www.viaembedded.com/en/products/minipcs/1850/1/ARTiGO_A1200.html

     **Bare PCB:** No
2. **VIA ARTiGO A1150**

   **CPU:** 1.0GHz VIA dual core Eden™ X2 64-bit processor,
   **GPU:** VIA Chrome 9
   **RAM Memory:** Up to 4GB of DDR3 1066 SODIMM RAM, 
   **NAND Flash:** None,
   **Storage:** 2.5” SATA, optional SD,
   **I/O:** HDMI, USB device port, 4 USB 2.0 ports, VGA, Gigabit LAN, 
   **Other Features:** HD, MPEG-2, WMV9, VC1 & H.264 video decoding hardware acceleration
   **Site:** http://www.viaembedded.com/en/products/minipcs/1650/1/ARTiGO_A1150_(Pico-ITX).html

     **Bare PCB:** No

### ARM based

---

1. **Rikomagic MK802**

   **CPU:** 1.0GHz Cortex-A8
   **SOC:** Allwinner A10,
   **GPU:** MALI400MP OpenGL ES 2.0,
   **RAM Memory:** 1GB / 512MB DDR3
   **NAND Flash:** 4GB
   **Storage:** microSD
   **I/O:** HDMI, Wifi 802.11b/g, WAPI (Ralink8188), 2 (USB + mini USB OTG)
   **Other Features:** 
   **Site:** http://store.cloudsto.com/rikomagic/rikomagic-mk802-detail.html

     **Bare PCB:** No
2. **Rikomagic MK802II**

   **CPU:** 1.0GHz Cortex-A8
   **SOC:** Allwinner A10,
   **GPU:** MALI400MP OpenGL ES 2.0,
   **RAM Memory:** 1GB / 512MB DDR3
   **NAND Flash:** 4GB
   **Storage:** microSD
   **I/O:** HDMI, Wifi 802.11b/g, WAPI (Ralink8188), 2x Micro USB, 1x USB2.0, 
   **Other Features:** 
   **Site:** http://store.cloudsto.com/rikomagic/rikomagic-mk802-ii-detail.html

     **Bare PCB:** No
3. **Mele A1000**

   **CPU:** 1GHz+ Cortex-A8,
   **SOC:** Allwinner A10,
   **GPU:** MALI400MP OpenGL ES 2.0
   **RAM Memory:** 512MB DDR3
   **NAND Flash:** 4GB
   **Storage:** SD, SATA
   **I/O:** HDMI, CVBS, VGA, Audio R+L, optical SPDIF, Ethernet 10/100Mbps, Wifi 802.11b/g/n WAPI(Ralink8188), UART, USB 
   **Other Features:** 
   **Site:**  ??

     **Bare PCB:** No
4. **Rhombus-Tech A10 EOMA-68**

   **CPU:** 1.2ghz Cortex A8 ARM Core
   **SOC:** Allwinner A10
   **GPU:** MALI400MP OpenGL ES 2.0 
   **RAM Memory:** 1GB DDR3
   **NAND Flash:** 1Gb - 16Gb
   **Storage:** Micro-SD, SATA
   **I/O:** HDMI, TV-Out, GPIO, I2C, PWM, Keyboard Matrix (8x8), built-in Resistive Touchscreen Controller, 4 SDIO interfaces (SD 3.0, UHI class), USB 2.0 Host as well as a 2nd USB-OTG Interface, 10/100Mb Ethernet
   **Other Features:** 
   **Site:** http://rhombus-tech.net/allwinner_a10/

     **Bare PCB:** No
5. **Gooseberry board**

   **CPU:** 1.2ghz Cortex A8 ARM Core (up to 1.5Ghz)
   **SOC:** Allwinner A10
   **GPU:** MALI400MP OpenGL ES 2.0
   **RAM Memory:** 512MB
   **NAND Flash:** 4GB
   **Storage:** Micro SD
   **I/O:** HDMI, 1x Mini Usb, Wifi, Audio 3.5mm Earphone Jack
   **Other Features:** 
   **Site:** http://gooseberry.atspace.co.uk/

     **Bare PCB:** Yes
6. **A13-OLinuXino**

   **CPU:** 1GHz A13 Cortex A8
   **SOC:** Allwinner A13
   **GPU:** MALI400MP OpenGL ES 2.0
   **RAM Memory:** 512 MB
   **NAND Flash:** optional 4GB
   **Storage:** SD
   **I/O:** 3 + 1 USB Host, 3 available for users 1 for (optional) WIFI RTL8188CU 802.11n 150Mbit module on board, 1 USB OTG which can power the board,
   VGA video output, LCD signals available on connector so you still can use LCD if you disable VGA/HDMI, Audio Output,Microphone Input,RTC PCF8536 on board for real time clock and alarms,5 Keys on board for android navigation,UEXT connector for connecting addtional UEXT modules like Zigbee, Bluetooth, Relays,GPIO connector with 68/74 pins and these signals: 17 for adding NAND flash; 22 for connecting LCDs; 20+4 including 8 GPIOs which can be input, output, interrupt sources; 3x I2C; 2x UARTs; SDIO2 for connectinf SDcards and modules; 5 system pins: +5V, +3.3V, GND, RESET, NMI Optional low cost 7" LCD with touchscreen
   **Other Features:** 
   **Site:** https://www.olimex.com/Products/OLinuXino/A13/A13-OLinuXino-WIFI-DEV/

     **Bare PCB:** Yes
7. **VIA APC 8750**

   **CPU:** 800 MHz ARM11
   **SOC:** VIA WonderMedia 8750
   **GPU:** OpenGL ES 2.0 
   **RAM Memory:** DDR3 512MB
   **NAND Flash:** 3GB
   **Storage:**  microSD
   **I/O:** HDMI, VGA, USB 2.0 (x4), Audio out / Mic in, 10/100 Ethernet
   **Other Features:** 
   **Site:** http://apc.io/

     **Bare PCB:** Yes
8. **BeagleBoard Rev. C4**

   **CPU:** 720 MHz ARM Cortex-A8 
   **SOC:** TI OMAP3530 
   **GPU:** PowerVR SGX 
   **RAM Memory:** 256 MB
   **NAND Flash:** 256 MB
   **Storage:** SD/MMC
   **I/O:** HDMI, S-Video, Stereo in and out jacks, 1 USB, USB OTGRS-232 port, JTAG, I2C, I2S, SPI, MMC/SD
   **Other Features:** 
   **Site:** http://beagleboard.org/hardware/design

     **Bare PCB:** Yes
9. **BeagleBoard-xM**

   **CPU:** 1 GHz Cortex-A8
   **SOC:** TI DM3730
   **GPU:** PowerVR SGX
   **RAM Memory:** 512 MB
   **NAND Flash:** 4 GB
   **Storage:** MicroSD
   **I/O:** HDMI, S-Video, Stereo in and out jacks, 4x USB, 10/100 Ethernet,RS-232 port, JTAG connector, Camera port, I2C, I2S, SPI, MMC/SD
   **Other Features:** 
   **Site:**  http://beagleboard.org/hardware/design

     **Bare PCB:** Yes
10. **BeagleBone**

    **CPU:** (500MHZ-USB Powered, 720MHZ-DC Powered) Cortex A8
    **SOC:** TI AM3359 Sitara
    **GPU:** PowerVR SGX530
    **RAM Memory:** 256MB DDR2 
    **NAND Flash:**
    **Storage:** microSD
    **I/O:** USB 2.0 Client Port, Host Port, JTAG, more through Expansion boards 
    **Other Features:** 
    **Site:**  http://beagleboard.org/hardware/design

      **Bare PCB:** Yes
11. **PandaBoard**

    **CPU:** 1GHz Dual-core ARM Cortex-A9 MPCore
    **SOC:** OMAP4430
    **GPU:** PowerVR SGX540
    **RAM Memory:** 1GB DDR2
    **NAND Flash:** 
    **Storage:** SD/MMC
    **I/O:** HDMI, DVI-D, LCD, 10/100 Ethernet, 802.11 b/g/n (WiLink™ 6.0), 
    Bluetooth v2.1 + EDR, General purpose (I2C, GPMC, USB, MMC, DSS, ETM), Camera, 
    LCD, JTAG, UART/RS-232
    **Other Features:** 
    **Site:** http://pandaboard.org/

      **Bare PCB:** Yes
12. **PandaBoard ES**

    **CPU:** 1.2 GHz Dual-core ARM Cortex-A9 MPCore
    **SOC:** OMAP4460 
    **GPU:** PowerVR SGX540
    **RAM Memory:** 1GB DDR2
    **NAND Flash:** 
    **Storage:** SD/MMC
    **I/O:** HDMI, DVI-D, LCD, 10/100 Ethernet, 802.11 b/g/n (WiLink™ 6.0), 
    Bluetooth v2.1 + EDR, General purpose (I2C, GPMC, USB, MMC, DSS, ETM), Camera, 
    LCD, JTAG, UART/RS-232
    **Other Features:** 
    **Site:** http://pandaboard.org/

      **Bare PCB:** Yes
13. **Cotton Candy**

    **CPU:** 1.2 GHz dual-core ARM Cortex-A9
    **SOC:** Samsung Exynos 4210
    **GPU:** MALI400MP OpenGL ES 2.0
    **RAM Memory:** 1 GB
    **NAND Flash:** 
    **Storage:** MicroSD SDXC
    **I/O:** HDMI with audio, Wifi 802.11 b/g/n, Bluetooth 2.1 + EDR
    **Other Features:** 
    **Site:** http://www.fxitech.com/products/

      **Bare PCB:** No
14. **CuBox**

    **CPU:** 800 MHz ARMv7
    **SOC:** Marvell Armada 510 (88AP510)
    **GPU:** Vivante GC600
    **RAM Memory:** 1 GB DDR3
    **NAND Flash:** 
    **Storage:** MicroSD, 1 x eSATA
    **I/O:** HDMI, S/PDIF, 2 x USB, 1000baseT Ethernet, Infra-red receiver with LIRC support 
    **Other Features:** 
    **Site:** http://www.solid-run.com/products/cubox

      **Bare PCB:** No
15. **Hawkboard**

    **CPU:** 300-MHz ARM926EJ
    **SOC:** TI OMAP-L138
    **GPU:** ??
     
    **RAM Memory:** 128 MByte
    **NAND Flash:** 128 MByte
    **Storage:** SATA
    **I/O:** VGA, Composite IN, USB 1.1 Host, USB 2.0 OTG, VPIF, UPP, PRU, LCDC, 2x UART, 2x SPI , 1x I2C , eCAP, eHRPWM, GPIO, JTAG
    **Other Features:** 
    **Site:** http://www.hawkboard.org/

      **Bare PCB:** Yes
16. **IGEP v2**

    **CPU:** ARM Cortex A8 1GHz
    **SOC:** Ti DM3730
    **GPU:** SGX530 @ 200 MHz
    **RAM Memory:** 512 MB
    **NAND Flash:** 512 MB
    **Storage:** MicroSD
    **I/O:** DVI-D, TFT Interface 24 bit, Stereo audio in / out, USB host + Mini OTG host/slave, 10/100 Mb BaseT, Wifi 802.11 b/g, Bluetooth BC4 - Class 2.0, 3 x UART, Expansion boards available, McBSP, McSPI, I2C, GPIO
    **Other Features:** 
    **Site:** http://igep.es/products/processor-boards/igepv2-board 

      **Bare PCB:** Yes
17. **IGEP COM Proton & Module**

    **CPU:** 1GHZ ARM CORTEX A8 (720Mhz for OMAP3530)
    **SOC:** DM3730 (optional OMAP3530)
    **GPU:** SGX 530 (200Mhz), (110Mhz for OMAP3530)
    **RAM Memory:** 512 MB
    **NAND Flash:** 512 MB
    **Storage:** MicroSD
    **I/O:** 1 x USB 2.0 OTG, JTAG, Expansion: USB, DDS, Camera, uart, SPI, McBSP, I2C, keypad
    **Other Features:** 
    **Site Module:** http://igep.es/products/processor-boards/igep-com-module
    **Site Proton:** http://igep.es/products/processor-boards/igep-com-proton

      **Bare PCB:** Yes
18. **Gumstix Overo series**

    **CPU:** ARM Cortex-A8 Up to 1GHz
    **SOC:** AM3703, DM3730, OMAP3503, OMAP3530
    **GPU:** ??
    **RAM Memory:** 512MB or 256MB
    **NAND Flash:** 0 - 512MB
    **Storage:** microSD
    **I/O:** Many, by using various 
    **Other Features:** 
    **Site:** https://www.gumstix.com/store/index.php?cPath=33

      **Bare PCB:** Yes
19. **Origen Board**

    **CPU:** 1.4GHz Dual Core Cortex-A9
    **SOC:** Samsung Exynos 4
    **GPU:** MALI400MP OpenGL ES 2.0
    **RAM Memory:** 1GB (POP Type)
    **NAND Flash:** 
    **Storage:** 2 x SD/MMC
    **I/O:** mini HDMI, LCD, SDcard, Serial, USB 2.0 Host x 2, USB 2.0 Device
    JTAG , Ethernet (10/100 Mbps), HDMI support, WiFi/Bluetooth Combo, RS232, JTAG, camera
    **Other Features:** 
    **Site:** http://www.origenboard.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

      **Bare PCB:** Yes
20. **Nimbus**

    **CPU:** ARM9E
    **SOC:** 1.2 GHz ARM Marvell Kirkwood 88F6281
    **GPU:** ??
    **RAM Memory:** 512MB DDR2
    **NAND Flash:** 512MB
    **Storage:**
    **I/O:** USB 2.0 Host, Gigabit Ethernet
    **Other Features:** 
    **Site:** http://www.ionicsplug.com/nimbus.html

      **Bare PCB:** No
21. **Stratus**

    **CPU:** ARM9E
    **SOC:** 1.2 GHz ARM Marvell Kirkwood 88F6281
    **GPU:** ??
    **RAM Memory:** 512MB DDR2
    **NAND Flash:** 512MB
    **Storage:**
    **I/O:** USB 2.0 Host, Gigabit Ethernet, 802.11 b/g (Micro-AP / Client) WPS support on Client Mode, Bluetooth 2.1 + EDR, ZWave (US, EU), ZigBee (802.15.4)
    **Other Features:** 
    **Site:** http://www.ionicsplug.com/stratus.html

      **Bare PCB:** No
22. **Cirrus**

    **CPU:** ARM9E
    **SOC:** 2.0 GHz Processor Speed Marvell Armada 88F6282
    **GPU:** ??
    **RAM Memory:** 1 GB DDR3
    **NAND Flash:** 512MB
    **Storage:** SATA 
    **I/O:** WLAN 802.11 b/g/n (configurable as client or uAP),WPS Support on Client Mode, Dual Gigabit Ethernet Ports at 10/100/1000 Base-T, USB 2.0 Host (Type A)
    **Other Features:** 
    **Site:** http://www.ionicsplug.com/cirrus.html

      **Bare PCB:** No
23. **SheevaPlug dev kit (Basic)**

    **CPU:** ARM9E
    **SOC:** 1.2Ghz Marvel Kirkwood 6281
    **GPU:** ??
    **RAM Memory:** 512MB DDR2
    **NAND Flash:** 512 MB
    **Storage:** SDIO
    **I/O:** USB 2.0 Host, RTC w/ Battery
    **Other Features:** 
    **Site:** http://www.globalscaletechnologies.com/t-sheevaplugdetails.aspx 

      **Bare PCB:** No
24. **GuruPlug Server**

    **CPU:** ARM9E
    **SOC:** 1.2Ghz Marvel Kirkwood 6281
    **GPU:** ??
    **RAM Memory:** 512MB DDR2
    **NAND Flash:** 512MB
    **Storage:** MicroSD
    **I/O:** 1 x Gb Ethernet, 2 x USB 2.0, Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, RTC w/Battery
     
    **Other Features:** 
    **Site:** http://www.globalscaletechnologies.com/p-49-guruplug-server-standard.aspx

      **Bare PCB:** No
25. **GuruPlug Display**

    **CPU:** ARMv5
    **SOC:** 800MHz Marvell ARMADA 168
    **GPU:** ??
    **RAM Memory:** 512MB DDR2
    **NOR Flash:** 4Mb 
    **Storage:** MicroSD Slot (w/ 4GB card), Internal MicroSD card – 8GB
    **I/O:** 1 x Ethernet 10/100 Mbps, 4 x USB 2.0 ports (Host),1 x USB 2.0 OTG micro-AB port (Device/Host),1 x MicroSD Socket (w/ 4GB card),1 x MicroSD Socket w/ JTAG I/F option, 1 x Internal MicroSD Socket (w/ 8GB card), 1 x Serial Port over USB (for console),1 x HDMI Output Port with CEC, RTC w/ Battery
    **Other Features:** 
    **Site:** 

      **Bare PCB:** No
26. **DreamPlug**

    **CPU:** ARM9E
    **SOC:** 1.2Ghz Marvel Kirkwood 6281
    **GPU:** ??
    **RAM Memory:** 512MB DDR2 
    **NAND Flash:** 4 GB
    **Storage:** eSATA, SD
    **I/O:** 2 x Gigabit Ethernet 10/100/1000 Mbps, 2 x USB 2.0 ports (Host),1 x eSATA 2.0 port- 3Gbps SATAII, 1 x SD Socket for user expansion/application, WiFi: 802.11 b/g/n, Bluethooth 3.0, JTAG, S/PDIF 
    **Other Features:** 
    **Site:** http://www.globalscaletechnologies.com/p-54-dreamplug-devkit.aspx

      **Bare PCB:** No
27. **D2Plug**

    **CPU:** ARM v6/v7
    **SOC:** 800MHz Marvell PXA510
    **GPU:** ??
    **RAM Memory:** 1GB DDR3
    **NOR Flash:** 16Mb SPI NOR FLASH 
    **Storage:** SD, 1 x eSATAp, Powered eSATA & USB combo
    **I/O:** 1 x Ethernet 10/100/1000 Mbps, 2 x USB 2.0 Host port, 1 x eSATAp – Powered eSATA and USB 2.0 Host combo port, 1 x USB 2.0 Device port, 1 x SD card slot, 1 x HDMI 1080p Output port with CEC, 1 x VGA Output port, 1 x Audio Line OUT, 1 x MIC IN, 1 x S/PDIF optical out, WiFi: 802.11 b/g/n,Bluetooth 3.0 + HS, JTAG
    **Other Features:** 
    **Site:** http://www.globalscaletechnologies.com/p-53-d2-plug.aspx

      **Bare PCB:** No
28. **Trim-Slice series**

    **CPU:** dual-core ARM Cortex A9 @ 1 GHz
    **SOC:** NVIDIA Tegra 2
    **GPU:** GeForce GPU 
    **RAM Memory:** 1 GB DDR2
    **NAND Flash:**
    **Storage:** SD, microSD, SATA, optional SSD or 2.5 HDD
    **I/O:** HDMI, optional DVI, S/PDIF 5.1, Stereo line-out, in, 4 USB 2.0, Micro USB device, Gigabit Ethernet, optional 802.11n, optional Bluetooth 2.0,optional video in, JTAG, UART
    **Other Features:** 
    **Site:** http://trimslice.com/web/trim-slice-features

      **Bare PCB:** No
29. **Snowball**

    **CPU:** 1GHz Dual Cortex A9
    **SOC:** STEricsson Nova A9500
    **GPU:** Mali 400
    **RAM Memory:** 1GB DDR2
    **NAND Flash:** 4 / 8GByte e-MMC
    **Storage:** Micro-SD
    **I/O:** HDMI, CVBS, Audio, 10/100Mbits Ethernet, optional 802.11 b/g/n, Bluetooth 2.1+EDR, GPS, Built-in WIFI (removable antenna) 802.11 b/g/n, optional video in, JTAG, UART, Li-Ion Charger, RS232, Expansion Connectors, A lot of sensors 
    **Other Features:** 
    **Site:** ?? (cannot find the official site)

      **Bare PCB:** Yes
30. **i.MX53 Quick Start Board**

    **CPU:** 1Ghz ARM Cortex™-A8
    **SOC:** Freescale i.MX535
    **GPU:** ??
    **RAM Memory:** 1GB DDR3
    **NAND Flash:**
    **Storage:** SD/MMC, microSD
    **I/O:** VGA, LVDS, optional HDMI, 3-axis Accelerometer, JTAG, UART, SPDIF, 10/100 Ethernet, 2x high–speed USB Host port, 1x Micro USB Device port
    **Other Features:** 
    **Site:** http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=IMX53QSB

      **Bare PCB:** Yes
31. **Pineriver H24/MiniX**

    **CPU:** 1GHz Cortex-A8
    **SOC:** Allwinner A10
    **GPU:** Mali400
    **RAM Memory:** 512MB
    **NAND Flash:** 4GB
    **Storage:** Support External storage via USB host /Support External storage via TF card  
    **I/O:** HDMI, CVBS, USB 2.0 host, USB OTG, Built-in WIFI module, Audio
    **Other Features:** 
    **Site:** http://www.pineriver.cn/eshowProDetail.asp?ProID=1531

      **Bare PCB:** No
32. **Smallart UHOST**

    **CPU:** ARM®Cortex™-A8@1.0GHz
    **SOC:** Allwinner A10
    **GPU:** Mali400
    **RAM Memory:** 1GB DRAM 
    **NAND Flash:** 4 GB
    **Storage:** microSD
    **I/O:** HDMI, Wifi 802.11 b/g/n, Mini USB 
    **Other Features:** 
    **Site:** http://www.smallart.com.cn/en/pro.asp

      **Bare PCB:** No
33. **Genesi Efika MX Smarttop**

    **CPU:** ARM Cortex-A8 800MHz
    **SOC:** Freescale i.MX515
    **GPU:** ?? 
    **RAM Memory:** 512MB RAM
    **NAND Flash:** 8GB
    **Storage:** 8GB Internal SSD
    **I/O:** HDMI, 2x USB 2.0, 10/100Mbit/s Ethernet, 802.11 b/g/n WiFi
    **Other Features:** 
    **Site:** https://www.genesi-usa.com/store/details/11

      **Bare PCB:** No
34. **Embest DevKit8600**

    **CPU:** 720MHz ARM Cortex-A8
    **SOC:** TI’s Sitara AM3359
    **GPU:** SGX530
    **RAM Memory:** 512MB DDR3
    **NAND Flash:** 512MB
    **Storage:** SD Card
    **I/O:** 10/100/1000Mbps Ethernet, TFT LCD, VGA via module, USB2.0 OTG, USB 2.0 host, WiFi/Bluetooth Module, Debug, 4x serial, RS485, CAN, GPMC, JTAG, ADC, SPI, I2C, Audio in, Audio out, buttons
    **Other Features:** 
    **Site:** http://www.armkits.com/product/devkit8600.asp

      **Bare PCB:** Yes
35. **Embest SBC8018**

    **CPU:** ARM926EJ-S Core 
    **SOC:** TI AM1808
    **GPU:** ??
    **RAM Memory:** 128MB Mobile DDR 
    **NAND Flash:** 128MB
    **Storage:** SD card, SATA, SATAII
    **I/O:** LCD/Touch Screen interface, Two Camera interfaces, SPI, I2C, McBSP, 3x UART, GPIO, RTC w/ battery, buttons, 10/100Mbps Ethernet 
    **Other Features:** 
    **Site:** http://www.armkits.com/product/sbc8018.asp

      **Bare PCB:** Yes
36. **Embest SBC8530**

    **CPU:** 1GHz ARM Cortex-A8
    **SOC:** TI DM3730
    **GPU:** ??
    **RAM Memory:** 512MB 
    **NAND Flash:** 512MB 
    **Storage:** SD Card
    **I/O:** UART, 4 USB Host, USB OTG, Ethernet, WiFi/BT, Audio, TF, Supports 24-bit TFT LCD, DVI-D and S-Video Output Display, Optional VGA, Camera, GPS, GPRS, WiFi and 3G Modules,10/100Mbps Ethernet
    **Other Features:** 
    **Site:** http://www.armkits.com/product/sbc8530.asp

      **Bare PCB:** Yes
37. **Embest DevKit8500D**

    **CPU:** 1GHz ARM Cortex-A8
    **SOC:** DM3730
    **GPU:** POWERVR SGX
    **RAM Memory:** 512MB
    **NAND Flash:** 512MB, optional 2GB iNAND
    **Storage:**
    **I/O:** UART, 4 USB Host, USB OTG, Ethernet, Audio, TF, Keyboard, Jtag,  Supports 24-bit TFT LCD, DVI-D and S-Video Output Display, Supports VGA, Camera, WiFi, GPS, GPRS, 3G Functions through Modules, 10/100M Ethernet 
    **Other Features:** 
    **Site:** http://www.armkits.com/product/devkit8500d.asp

      **Bare PCB:** Yes
38. **Cubieboard**

    **CPU:** 1GHz ARM Cortex-A8
    **SOC:** Allwinner A10
    **GPU:** Mali400
    **RAM Memory:** 512MB/1GB
    **NAND Flash:** 4GB
    **Storage:** 1 micro SD slot, 1 SATA
    **I/O:** HDMI, 2 USB Host, 96 extend pin including I2C, SPI, RGB/LVDS, CSI/TS, FM-IN, ADC, CVBS, VGA, SPDIF-OUT, R-TP, 10/100M Ethernet 
    **Other Features:** 
    **Site:** http://cubieboard.org/

      **Bare PCB:** Yes

---

**Note:**
Base for this list is the PDF created by omgfire, I added information where missing and corrected information from the original specifications provided by the company or organization that created the device.

Comment: This is the list is also helpful ... but I can't mark two answers as correct .. Thanks for your answer

Comment: We should try to aim for answers to stand on their own merit, rather than just link to another site. Would you consider summarising the information here?

Comment: +1 for posting list of alternatives. @AlexChamberlain you should consider +1 also.

Comment: So, that was quite a job, too bad that it just remains a flat list, it would me much more useful in a different format. Some format where it is actually possible to compare the data of the various boards. But I am afraid that is not possible, or am I wrong?

Comment: a new one to add to the list: [Cubieboard](http://cubieboard.org/)

Comment: Take +1, thanks. And what about prices ?)

Comment: C.H.I.P $9 Linux board: https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1598272670/chip-the-worlds-first-9-computer

Answer (score 17):

Raspberry Pi is quite enough hardware for XBMC. Most of the problems are in the XBMC software implementation, just wait them to be resolved.

However, raymii.org does have a nice list of Linux compatible PCs here:
http://raymii.org/cms/p_Small_Linux_PCs_overview

http://java.net/downloads/mobileandembedded/Assets/SBC_comparison44-1.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Raspbmc worked great (with a bit safe overclocking)
and in RC 5 there will be the new raspberry pi turbo mode.

Really the best option in my opinion ( I still have my HUGE HTPC but for the other TV's it's RaspBMC all the way)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in any way, you just state that you don't have the issue the OP is having.