# Project needs multiple PWM

Tags: gpio, pwm, wiringpi

I'm working on a project that needs three (or more) PWM pins to work. But unlike Arduino, the Raspberry PI B+ has just one PWM pin. I've searched for solutions and I found that I can use the [WiringPi](https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/wiringpi/) to emulate PWM using software. Is this the best solution? Anybody has a better one?

Comment: What specifically are the three PWM pins for?

Comment: Acceleration control and Servo.

Comment: There's also pigpio that can do software PWM, see http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41140/gpio-library-for-c/41141#41141 Sorry, Joan, I didn't see your answer while posting this comment. Anyway the linked Q&A is related - to whom it may concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi B+ has two accessible dedicated hardware PWM channels.

Hardware timed PWM is available on all the accessible GPIO.

See my [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) library.

Comment: Is this a good solution for servos and acceleration control?

Comment: Yes to servos.  What do you mean by acceleration control?  If you mean varying a DC motor speed then yes.

Comment: Is this lib similar to WiringPi?

Comment: Not really.  The library is written in C.  That's the only thing in common.

Answer (score 1):

Studying the [WiringPI](http://raspi.tv/2013/how-to-use-wiringpi2-for-python-on-the-raspberry-pi-in-raspbian) library I found that I can easily handle the PWN on any pin:

```
# GPIO port numbers  
import wiringpi2 as wiringpi  
wiringpi.wiringPiSetupGpio()  
wiringpi.pinMode(25, 0) # sets GPIO 25 to input  
wiringpi.pinMode(24, 1) # sets GPIO 24 to output  
wiringpi.pinMode(18, 2) # sets GPIO 18 to PWM mode
```

Comment: I'm not sure if wiringPi can drive both the dedicated PWM channels.  wiringPi PWM on arbitary GPIO will be software timed, servos in particular may have problems with jitter.