# Are all arduino modules compatible with raspberry pi

Tags: arduino

I have arduino uno, nano and mega boards with many modules (relay, ir remote, ultrasonic sensors, etc) and they works well together.

I got raspberry pi 3 model b. Can I use my arduino modules with my raspberry pi?

Comment: Not directly, but you can get adapter boards to be able to plug in Arduino boards into the RPi. Like [this one](https://www.seeedstudio.com/Arduino-Adapter-For-Raspberry-Pi-p-2443.html) from Seeed Studio.

Comment: Very closely related: **[How to use Arduino devices with Raspberry Pi?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/49772/5538)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, NO.

Arduino works on 5V so any module which outputs 5V levels can't be used. These can often be used with level converters.

Some will work, and I have used a few. You need to study each module.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use all modules. Some of them are incompatible due to the power requirements as @Milliways mentioned. Still, you can connect your prefferable arduino to your raspberry through USB and do whatever you wish through serial port communication - just like you do with your pc.