# Accidentally fed 12V to the 5V-pin of Rpi2

Tags: gpio, power-supply, usb-power

After it happened, smoke comes out near the micro USB port of the rpi.
I replugged the power supply of he rpi but this time, the power LED(red) doesn't turn ON while the green LED keeps on blinking. Did I broke my Pi? What just happened?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate... from a few hours ago... from the same user... [rPi2 model B v1.1 smoke comes out near power port](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/75052/rpi2-model-b-v1-1-smoke-comes-out-near-power-port)

Comment: Kilokhertz, do not post the same question multiple times.

Comment: I just reconstruct my question into a clear question.