# SIM900 A6 GPRS GSM Module and Rpi4B UART Communication Problem

Tags: pi-4

I use a module same as [here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32908556501.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4dDWpIT0) with my RPI 4B and there were difficulties in communication between them two since the start. The module worked fine with my Arduino. It is connected via Rxd-Txd pins, 5V, ground and an additional external power to the module.

I'm trying to make it make calls with the help of python, and for now after entering `python -m serial.tools.miniterm /dev/ttyAMA0 115200` to the RPI terminal and typing in blindly "AT" I get a series of  backslashes which after a closer look turned out to be this: "␄␐␁␀" (EOT DLE SOH NUL). Which happily already is a response, but it's still not an "OK" that's expected after such command.

How could I solve this? I've surfed many google search results for RPI and SIM900 but none of them worked.

UPD:
*Serial is enabled, 
*Bluetooth disabled, 
*OS is Raspbian 10, 
*the module doesn't respond to any baudrate other than 115200
I'll try to get a level shifter and use it between RPi and module, the suggestion seems pretty logical and I wouldn't even think of devices using different voltages for UART. I'll post the results as soon as I get the shifter.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100806/discussion-on-question-by-oresto-sim900-a6-gprs-gsm-module-and-rpi4b-uart-commun).

Comment: *"It is connected via Rxd-Txd"* -> If the breakout the SIM is on uses 5V logic, then you should use a level shifter in the middle, otherwise you may get false highs one way and false lows the other, which will amount to miscommunication...

Comment: @goldilocks could you please explain further the use of a shifter? Do you mean that RPi uses 5V in the Rxd-Txd and the module uses 3.3V?

Comment: It is a secret known to few that *the Raspberry Pi uses 3.3V logic!*  And even fewer: *Most Arduinos are 5V logic!*  These are not the same.  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/49775/5538

Comment: @goldilocks I don't see how Arduino is relevant here. SIM900's are 3.3V devices, and so are Raspberries. The product description in the OP's link clearly states **Interface logic voltage: 3.3V**, so adding a level shifter will almost certainly not help.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I actually did not notice the product link.  The Arduino is relevant since the question states, *"The module worked fine with my Arduino."*, implying 5V logic worked whereas 3.3V is not.  I am not saying that definitively, but it is a possibility (except for the fact the datasheet I didn't read resolves this).  SIM900s are I believe 2.8V, which phones commonly use. For hobbyists they are of course sold on breakouts, usually with 3.3 or 5V interfaces to the UART.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Milliways said, you seem to use the wrong baudrate (115200 instead of 19200), unless of course you changed this too.

Edit: it appears that your module is configured to 115200. I would recommend you to get a USB to UART converter such as [this one](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32367985059.html) and make sure the module replies to the AT commands using a regular PC, to completely exclude RPi-related problems from the mix. If you can't get the module to work, it may simply be defective. It's not unheard of when ordering stuff on Aliexpress.

Comment: At the baudrate that you've proposed I get no answer. Actually the module didn't respond to any baudrate other than 115200 (which also was a recommended rate in the SIM900 RPi guides). I'm interested where did you even get such a number?

Comment: @Oresto https://www.google.com/search?q=SIM900+baudrate

Comment: well the module clearly refuses to communicate at the baudrate you proposed

Comment: @Oresto I understand that, I just explained where I got the number from.

Answer (score 1):

This "Question" is lacking detail (OS, did you enable serial) **BUT** the fundamental problem is you are trying to use `/dev/ttyAMA0` which is connected to Bluetooth (except in the unlikely circumstance that you changed this).

See [How do I make serial work on the Raspberry Pi3 , Pi3B+, PiZeroW](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/8697)

Comment: I had added `dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt` to the end of the config.txt in boot, so I guess yeah I've Bluetooth disabled

Comment: So I've got Raspbian 10 buster and serial is of course enabled